# 'virtual box could not be found while running vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

When the following command is executed:

```
vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
```

I am receiving the following error:

> The provider 'virtual box,1.1.0' could not be found, but was requested to
>       back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: weird, do you have virtualbox installed ? if you have not done anything, delete the `.vagrant` directory from your project and re-run

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the version of virtualbox is too high, choose a lower one.
It works when I alter virtualbox from 5.2 to 5.1 at vagrant 2.0.0.